# Just moved my site to ssl, but I have insecure content

Tags: javascript, http, ssl, https

I just moved my site to ssl, but I have insecure content. What exactly does this mean, what sort of changes do I need to make?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to search for your code for `http://` and change it to `https://`

Answer (score 4):

It means that your page is still loading some content over http (unsecured).
An easy way to find what it is that is being loaded is to watch the network tab in Developer Tools on chrome or [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) on firefox.

Answer (score 1):

It usually has to do with the `src` attribute, e.g. using jquery from googleapis. If so, change the source to `https` instead of `http`